# Iterating through tree datastructure using Treelib (Python)

Tags: python, data-structures, tree, decision-tree, treelib

I created some nodes by a Node-class and added them to a tree using Treelib.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, id, label, parent, type):
        self.id = id
        self.label = label
        self.parent = parent
        self.type = type

node = Node(id, label, parent, type)

if id == 'root':
   tree.create_node(tag=id, identifier=id, data=node)
else:
   tree.create_node(tag=id, identifier=id, parent=parent, data=node)
```

By calling tree.show() I got a great overview of the tree.
Now I want to iterate through the tree and get the data of each node defined earlier. (not only a single property by tree.show(data_property=""))

Do you got any ideas of how to work with the defined data?

My final goal is to calculate the tree structure like a decision tree and I dont find a good way using Treelib so far.

Comment: This code only creates one node. Can you edit and provide the code for a sample tree which we can run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First some remarks:

- I would use a different name for the class `Node`; as also TreeLib defines a `Node` class.
- As you use TreeLib there should not be a need to maintain parent-references in your own class instances. This is something that TreeLib manages for you already.

You can iterate over the nodes with the `all_nodes_itr` method, which will give you a TreeLib `Node` instance in each iteration. You can then access TreeLib attributes such as `identifier` or `parent`. For your own attributes, access the `data` attribute, and then the attribute you want to see (like `label`)

Here is a simplified script:

```
class MyNode(object):
    def __init__(self, id, label):
        self.id = id
        self.label = label


from treelib import Tree
tree = Tree()

def add_node(id, label, parent=None):
    node = MyNode(id, label)
    tree.create_node(tag=id, identifier=id, data=node, parent=parent)

add_node("world", "World")
add_node("north-america", "North America", "world")
add_node("europe", "Europe", "world")

for node in  tree.all_nodes_itr():
    print(node.identifier, node.data.label)
```

Comment: You can get the parent via the `parent` static method: for instance, you can access `tree.parent(node.identifier)`